# Find first event in Kafka KStream

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Is there any way to find only first event for corresponding key in KStream? I don't want to maintain separate state to track whether first event has arrived to given key.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a regular consumer for this. Just scan the topic for the key you're interested in, then stop consuming when you see it